# How to find a matrix that when multiplied with its transpose, creates a known PSD matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a symmetric PSD matrix A that looks like this:

```
| 1 1 0 0 |
| 1 1 0 0 |
| 0 0 1 1 |
| 0 0 1 1 |
```

In many literature it is mentioned that a symmetric matrix A is PSD iff, A equals the multiplication of some matrix M with its own transpose:

> A = (M^T)M

Here I quote the explanation from [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html)

My question is, how one can find this matrix M? since there are probably many numbers of such matrix. In this [book](http://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf), on page 142 it is said that computing M can be done in polynomial time.

**EDIT**

> Does M must a square matrix? how to compute M, if we want M with
>   certain dimension?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is called Cholesky factorization. You will find easily find lots of material about it.

Comment: In you example, $M=(\sqrt2/2)A$ will do.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek OK, but to my understanding in Cholesky factorization, M is assumed to be square matrix. Is it possible if M is not square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one such matrix, but in general, the one matrix that is most often studied is the one obtained by the [**Cholesky decomposition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)

Comment: OK, but to my understanding in Cholesky factorization, M is assumed to be square matrix. Is it possible if M is not square?

Comment: @BolbazarMarme Sure, there *might* exist a smaller matrix that also yields $A$, but to find that, you would probably have to resort to SVD decompositions...

Comment: An eigendecomposition is sufficient. If $A=V\Sigma V^T$ and $\Sigma$ has only $r<n$ nonzero diagonal entries, then you can take $M=\begin{bmatrix}U&0\end{bmatrix}\Sigma^{1/2}V^T$ where $U$ is any $r\times r$ orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$$
M=\pmatrix{ 1&1&0&0&\\0&0&1&1}
$$
since
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1} =\pmatrix{1\\1} \pmatrix{1&1}.
$$